# find modulus exponentiation for biginteger in matlab

Tags: matlab, module, biginteger, modulus, modulo

I want to calculate modulo exponentiation for Biginteger in Matlab.

```
a^b mod n = d
```

Example:

```
a=java.math.BigInteger('878');
b=java.math.BigInteger('8097');
c=java.math.BigInteger('961');
d=modPow(a,b,n)
```

How can I calculate unknown `n` in this Biginteger equation if `a`, `b`, `d` are given?

```
a=35367
b=453467
a^b mod n =16
```

or

```
modPow(a,b,n)=16
n=?
```

If the answer to the equation is equal to, for example, `16` and we want to find the value of `n`, how do we write the modulo equation to solve the values of `n` in Matlab, even for larger numbers?
It can be defined that the number `n` be found up to `1000000` or `10^6`.

Thanks.

Comment: You want 1) to avoid using java types, 2) https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/powermod.html

Comment: It is very, very, very, unlikely that there is a unique solution for numbers of the size in your example. With more equations using the same modulus you can start to drastically reduce the number of solutions. For your example, it can be quickly determined that n=53 or n=167 or n=53*167 are possible solutions among many.